# Remove black space from top and bottom of SwiftUI VideoPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avkit

When the SwiftUI VideoPlayer is used, black space appears above and below the video. How can this black space be removed so that only the video with no extra space is shown. I haven't found any way to do this within SwiftUI.

```
 import SwiftUI
 import AVKit

 struct VideoView: View {
     let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1606269156~acl=%2A%2F1123020046.mp4%2A~hmac=8d8e8fd9cd3c9de1b25de66bfd291f420d634f43137346daaa163bc0fbaebb22/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/4047/11/295238750/1123020046.mp4?filename=What+Star+Wars+Can+Teach+Us+About+Swift.mp4")!)

     var body: some View {
         VStack {
             Spacer()
        
             VideoPlayer(player: player)
        
             Spacer()
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you try `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`?

Comment: Just tried it, no luck. I think the issue may be with the AVPlayer object. I haven't found any native swiftui way to fix this.

Comment: It looks like you need to access `videoGravity` from `AVPlayerLayer`. I don't think it's exposed by SwiftUI's VideoPlayer. You may need to use UIKit for this.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I'm not very familiar with UIKit though, it would be super helpful if it could be demonstrated how to get this functionality within a SwiftUI view hierarchy. I'm sure other people learning SwiftUI will hit this roadblock at some point as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
VideoPlayer(player: player)
  .aspectRatio(widthOfVideo / heightOfVideo, contentMode: .fit)
```

Comment: yeah that's the answer if you know the height and width. but you don't